# Image does not display after migration from ASP.NET MVC framework to ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

After migrating my ASP.NET MVC project to ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC, the images that are in the project folders are no longer appearing in the view.

Please, what is happening?

```
<img src="@ViewBag.ImagePath" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="" id="Image1">
```

Answer (score 0):

When using .net core you need to explicitly configure the application to serve static files like .css, .js or image files.

To configure this function go to your `Startup.cs` file, then inside the method `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` add the following line: `app.UseStaticFiles();` before `app.UseRouting();`

If your application is already configured to serve static files, please, leave a comment below so we can work on it.

---

Note that in .NET Core image files need to be located inside `wwwroot > images` and refered like this `<img src="~/images/Image1.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid" alt="" id="Image1">`

Comment: Yes, my application is already configured with app.UseStaticFiles(); before app.UseRouting();

Comment: Seems a silly question, but you had compared the `@ViewBag.ImagePath` value with the real URL?

Comment: Also, in .net core the images need to be inside wwwroot -> images folder

Comment: Dear Andre.Santarosa, very thanks. Resolved! I put the images inside wwwroot and is running ok.

Comment: Glad it helped! .NET Core implemented some changes that sometimes are tricky to find out =/ Please mark the answer as accepted so others can also find the solution easily =)

Answer (score 0):

In .net core the folder structure is different. Images need to be stored in wwwroot folder. Also you need to enable static files middleware in

> Startup.cs

file in

> Configure

method before using MVC or routing.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```